# Jquery accordion unknown content divs

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Effectively I want to say: "Grab all content between each occurrence of this class and wrap it up as a section.

I've got a standard implementation

```
    function hubTasks() {
    $("#Form_Form").accordion({
        header: ".FormHeading",
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        autoHeight: false,
        autoActivate: true
    });
}
```

But obviously only collects the first div under the header, there are unknown and unmodifiable divs underneath it I want to contain. The header class is repeated many times.

I attempted to use:

```
 $(".FormHeading").append("<div>");
```

To put a generic div tag under each FormHeading to use but it seems to always implement the following closing tag which creates an empty container.

How do I go about solving this?

Comment: Can you post your code on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: There isn't much to show, but as you see only the first element is included in the panel, how do I go about including all elements up to the next heading, remembering that I can't add a basic container to wrap them in http://jsfiddle.net/u37dxrbv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've solved this with a bit of dirty script but doesn't feel like the "correct" way of doing it.

```
    $(".FormHeading").each(function () {
        $(this).nextUntil(".FormHeading").wrapAll('<div class="accordion-content" />');
    });
```

If anyone has a better/cleaner method I'd love to know!

Comment: That is the perfect way to go about it